# Deleting Tables from Access in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a table from an excel file then querying that table.  Once I'm done with the table, I would like to drop it.  However I'm getting the error

```
 "Database engine could not lock table because "TableName" it is already in use by another program or process.
```

This is a logical error but I'm not sure how to close the table in VBA?  I tried CurrentDb.Close.  Is there.  I assume there's a way to close it since it'd be in the same session?  I'm using the following to drop the table:

```
 db.Execute "DROP TABLE TableName", dbFailOnError
```

Is it possible to delete the table or do I have to settle for only deleting the rows?

T hank you!

Comment: You should be able to.  Can you post the section of code? The recordset may need closed or Set RecordSet = Nothing works

Comment: And that's what I needed.  I didn't post all my code becasue it was just modifying a table / SQL queries, I assumed I was just missing something simple about a language I am not biggest fan of.  Post that as the answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks @JimmySmith

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drop the table like you tried. The table is locked if you have some open recordsets on it. Look for not closed connections to this table.

This is definitly a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the DROP statement, the recordset may need closed or Set RecordSet = Nothing works.